# what is the maximum limit that svnadmin load/dump file execute

Tags: svn, svnadmin, cvs2svn

I am migrating cvs and Subversion 1.6 repos to new subversion 1.8 server. I use cvs2svn for CVS dump and svnadmin dump to create dump files and load in new subversion server. My CVS repositories maximum size is 8 GB and Subversion repos 15 GB in size. 
1. **Can I use cvs2svn to dump 8 gb cvs repository**. cvs2svn will create dumpfile for 8 gb repository and will this dump can be loaded in subversion server. 
2. **can I use svnadmin dump (not delta) for 15 gb repository** and **will I be able to load in the new server.**
Is there any size limit or limitations on running cvs2svn conversion and svnadmin load and dump commands. Please share your approach and suggestions that I can follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on cvs2svn, but I can say that I recently dumped a 22GB repository into a 45GB dumpfile (45GB after gzip, who knows how much it would be without gzip). This dumpfile was then loaded into a new (1.9) repository without issues.

Comment: Great, to see your post. I have repositories around 10 GB so curious to know the learnings/suggestions who did this before. so that I can plan before migration. Now I can make room of double the space of cvs repositories while running cvs2svn tool. It helps me plan accordingly.  @Mark - what approach or best practice or do/don'ts you suggest for me from your learnings.

Comment: I didn't do much to prepare, I just dumped it and piped through gzip. I didn't dump with deltas, and I probably should have. The load took much longer than the dump (a couple hours to dump, a couple days to load, on ssd).

Comment: I didn't think about the time it would take to process the dump. Nice you posted. Documentation says, conversion needs more space. If 45 GB takes 2 days to load, how much TEMP space is required. How much you had as TEMP space.

Comment: The SSD that the import was done on had ~80GB free when I did the `svnadmin load`. I doubt it consumed much TEMP space, though, as it only deals with a single revision at a time (at least, when deltas aren't involved).

Comment: Another query is, I have checked the pre-requisite for cvs2svn (http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html#use-cvs) tool. It says, required software as Pythone and gdbm & python bindings. I have Python package and I am able to run the cvs2svn and create dump file. Have you installed gdbm & python bindings. Do you know how to check gdbm  and python bindings are installed. or just python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 is enough. I see couple of python libraries listed in "rpm -qa | grep python". So what exactly is required for running cvs2svn.

Comment: I check the gdbm using "rpm -qa| grep gdbm" but the required python bindings mentioned in the cvs2svn documentation is not clear on what python bindings are required. I mean the binding name if there are more bindings for python. Due to that i am not clear with the pre-requisite for cvs2svn. what are packages you installed for cvs2svn.